# Any reason to use Injector.resolveAndCreate() in a TypeScript A2 application?

Tags: angular

The existing Angular 2 documentation shows examples of using Injector.resolveAndCreate() to programmatically define providers and create an injector. Or Injector.resolveAndCreateChild() to create providers and a child injector. These are helpful to understand DI and providers.

But, is there any use case where it is necessary or helpful to use these directly if you're coding in TypeScript? Seems like A2 creates the Injectors for you automatically and gives decorator properties to register providers.

Also, is it even possible to programmatically add a provider to an existing component's injector? I know you can create a child injector and do other things, but not sure you can add a provider after an injector has been created.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a use case where I have found `resolveAndCreate` method very useful.  In such use case, I have followed a pattern similar to [MessagingMapper](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessagingMapper.html) where I have a series of events mapped to a series of Command classes.

Since my code needs to manually instantiate the Command classes, the code would need to call `Injector` to provide the dependency injections.

Below is a snippet of the code where `resolveAndCreate` is used:

```
private event_captured(eventArg:SignalBase):void {
    var eventName:string = eventArg.eventName;
    if (this.hasMap(eventName)) {
        var commandClass:any = this._commandMap[eventName];

        var providers:Array<Provider> = this.diProviders;
        var injector:Injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate(providers.concat(new Provider(commandClass, {useClass: commandClass})));
        var cmd:ICommand<SignalBase> = injector.get(commandClass);
        cmd.event = eventArg;
        cmd.execute();
    }
}
```